# What a driver does with the passengers?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, vernacular

When you drive a car and bring people somewhere what you do with them? I mean, the delivery process of people. How to pronounce the complete sentence?

Comment: You take the passengers to the store/church/work/train station.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: It depends on whether you're a taxi driver or a serial killer.

Comment: You *take them for a ride*, but literally.

Comment: I've considered the correct answer be "I'll drop <whom> off at the <where>". Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *drop them off* at their destination.

> Verb: drop off
>
> dróp óf
>
> 3. Leave at a destination; remove from a transport container
>      "drop off the passengers at the hotel";
>
>    - drop, set down, put down, unload, discharge

-- [WordWeb online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=drop+off)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "drove":

> He drove the passengers to their destination

Alternatively, you can use "took", but I would suggest adding more context as to who took them. In this case, adding "cab driver" clarifies how exactly he took them--via a car:

> The cab driver took the passengers to their destination

A probably less appealing alternative is "transported"

Comment: I rather like *transported*. That's what you do with passengers: you transport them.

Comment: Note that both drove and took are past tense.

Comment: @IvanBorisenko Only in these examples. A business person might say "When the meeting's over I will drive you to the station". If a police officer flagged someone down and asked them where they were going the driver might say "I'm taking my mother to her hospital appointment".

Comment: @RichardKayser I personally don't like polysyllabic words when simpler ones will do just fine

Answer (score 1):

Drivers *transport* passengers.

M-W:

> [*transport*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transport): to
>   transfer or convey from one place to another

Taxi drivers, limo drivers, bus drivers, train drivers, airplane pilots, etc. *transport* passengers from Point A to Point B. That's what they do, and what passengers are paying for.

**Note**: @AleksandrH mentioned "transported" as a "probably less appealing" alternative to "drove" and "took", but didn't expand on *transported* (or *transport*) as an answer.

Comment: To elaborate on my explanation, people will see it as pretentious if someone says "I will transport you to ___" as opposed to the much simpler "I will drive/take you to ____"

Comment: @AleksandrH The question can be interpreted in multiple ways. The OP didn't give an example sentence. If he had given your sentence, I would agree with you, but he didn't. I focused on the question title. Drivers transport people.